# Question about the definition of orientation in Vector Calculus and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach" by Hubbard.

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation, non-orientable-surfaces

I am trying to understand the definition of orientation as it is done in the book "Vector Calculus and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach" by Hubbard. What I really like about it is that he starts of with unit normals and unit tangents for surfaces and curves respectiely. Then orientation is defined using k-forms. It is called the "Unified approach". Then he says that these notions of orientation coincide.

[image]

**Questions:**

- What does "coinicide" mean? What I know is that two k-forms that are positive multiples of each other dertermine the same orientation (An introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Tu,p.239). But this uses equivalence classes and is a bit more technical.
- How does a normal vector of a surface determine an orientation in the sense that I get a basis for $T_{p}M$?
- How can I find a normal vector N from knowing $\omega(v_{1},v_{2})$. In other words why does $\omega(v_{1},v_{2})$ help to find an orientation in the sense of definition 6.5.6?
- Why is the determinant not used in definition 6.5.6? In definition 6.6.6 it is used.

I find the notion of orientation really confusing. Maybe in the 5th edition it is clearer defined. Unfortunately I don't have the latest version.

---

- Excerpt 1

[image]

- Excerpt 2

[image]

- Excerpt 3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How does a normal vector of a surface determine an orientation in the sense that I get a basis for $T_p M$?*

Why do you mention a basis here? According to the definition you gave, an orientation is defined by a non-zero $2$-form on $T_p M$ (and two $2$-forms give the same orientation if they differ by a positive scalar).

The answer is: given a normal vector $\vec{n}$, you can define a non-zero $2$-form $\omega_\vec{n}$ by
$$
\omega_\vec{n}(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2) = \det(\vec{n},\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2).
$$

---

*What does "coincide" mean?*

In the notation above, you could say (i.e. define) that the orientations defined by $\vec{n}$ and $\omega$ coincide if and only if the orientations defined by $\omega_\vec{n}$ and $\omega$ coincide. This in turn is equivalent to the fact that $\omega_\vec{n}$ and $\omega$ differ by a positive scalar.

With this convention, the first excerpt you give is a tautology.

---

*How can I find a normal vector $\vec{n}$ from knowing $\omega(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)$? In other words, why does $\omega(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2)$ help to find an orientation in the sense of definition 6.5.6?*

It's easier to answer the opposite question directly - given $\vec{n}$, you can produce a $2$-form $\omega_\vec{n}$ as described above. Conversely, if you are given $\omega$, then you can find an appropriate $\vec{n}$. Since there are exactly two normal vectors $\vec{n}_1,\vec{n}_2$ (differing by a sign), then one of them has to agree with $\omega$ - if $\vec{n}_1$ doesn't agree with $\omega$, then $\vec{n}_2$ has to.

---

Added later: **Relation with another notion of orientability.** In the source you gave, choosing an orientation amounts to choosing a non-zero $2$-form (up to a positive scalar). However, in your comments you have referred to another notion, in which an orientation means that some bases are positively oriented, and some are negatively oriented (as always, there are two possible choices for an orientation).

You can easily connect these two notions. Given a nonzero $2$-form $\omega$, you can say that a basis $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2$ is positively oriented if and only if $\omega(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2) > 0$.

Comment: I am not sure where you found the answer two the first question. Is it def. 6.6.6 or in the paragraph below def.6.5.7? I mentioned the basis of $T_{p}M$, becuase in my opinion this a notch too unintuitive opposed to -for example- the situation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using three vectors. I want to see the definition via forms as a formalisation/characterisation of the idea that $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is positive, $\det(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})>0$. I would interpret $N$ as some sort of "refrence point/quantity" with respect to which two vectors $w_{1},w_{2}$ are positively oriented and

Comment: as a tool to decide that, I would use $\det(N,v_{2},v_{3})>0$, since it convincingly captures the idea of orientation in $\mathbb{R}^3$(see Linear Algebra Through Geometry by Banchoff,p.158-159).

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question: I think I had the same thought as you.

However, I think what bothers me is that, at least too me, it is not clear form what is given in the text what an orientation defined by $\omega$ is supposed to be. I guess one could say that $v_{1},v_{2}$ is positively oriented, if $\omega(v_{1},v_{2})>0$. I fail to see why this is a „good“ definition of orientation, unless I can connect it to a more geometric situation.

Comment: 3rd Question: Do you mean choose the normal vector such that  $\det(N,w_{1},w_{2})>0$ or  $\det(-N,w_{1},w_{2})>0$?

I think any „outward pointing“ vector does job, if I am not mistaken. But wouldn’t any vector $v$ such that $\det(v,w_{1},w_{2})>0$ do the job too?

Comment: Ad 3. I've clarified this part a bit. The point is, if $N$ works, choose $N$, and If doesn't, choose $-N$. As you noted there's nothing special about normal vectors, you could work with any vector outside $T_p M$ (but your source focuses on normals to make its choice _almost_ unique).

Comment: Ad 1, 2. I see you're referencing to yet another notion of orientation, so I've added a brief comment on that. I think you'd be less confused (and more likely to get help) if you decided to state one definition, stick to that one as your primary definition, and then comparing everything else with it.

Comment: Ad 3. I agree, but isn't that what I meant? 

Ad. 1,2: The reason why I stated both is that I want to understand how they are connected. To me it seems that the normal vector definition is a bit unclear unless one adds $\det(N,v_{1},v_{2})$ to it, as it is a means to say what is „clockwise/counter clockwise/right/left“, which is, as far as I understand it, sort of the whole point of in introducing orientation. Having $\det(N,v_{1},v_{2})$ I think I get that this is equivalent to using some $\omega$, which is a positive multiple.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right about 3. I also agree that the normal vector definition is a bit odd. As you said, it relies on mentioning $\det(N,v_1,v_2)$, which is nothing else than relying on the orientation of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact you could see it a special case of a general construction: if $E = E_1 \oplus E_2$ and you are given orientations on two out of these three spaces, then there's a canonical way to define an orienation on the third space.